# missing x with no default. Calling functions within functions in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, sudoku

I'm writing a code to solve a sudoku puzzle using a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK4N8E6uNr4&t=912s) found from YouTube that has coded the same algorithm through Python. This code requires three functions to

1. Find an empty square.
2. insert a number into the empty square.
3. Test whether this number is valid to solve the puzzle.

This is using a backtracking algorithm for the solver.

I am having an issue when calling the functions together where i get the error:

```
Error in free_squ(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In if (empty_sq == FALSE) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: free_squ(x)
```

This is confusing as I only get it when running thIS code. So I can write other functions to call the individual functions to analyse the argument inserted into the overlying function:

```
function1(argument){
   function2(argument){
     function3(argument){
        ***DO STUFF***}}}
```

Why for the following code does function within the main function not recognise the argument?

```
sudoku_solve <- function(x){

  empty_sq <- free_squ(x) # Define a new object to give coordinates of empty square

  if(empty_sq == FALSE){ # If no empty square can be found

    return(x) # Return the matrix

  } else{

    empty_sq <- empty_sq  # Pointless line kept for clarity

  }
  for(i in c(1:9)){ # Integers to insert into the found empty square

    if(valid(x, i, empty_sq) == TRUE){ # can the intiger be placed in this square?

      x[empty_sq[1], empty_sq[2]] = i # if i valid, insert into empty square
    } 


    if(sudoku_solve()){ # are all i's valid?

      return(TRUE) # All i's valid

    } else{

      x[empty_sq[1], empty_sq[2]] = 0 # reset the initial try and try again with another
    }
}
  return(FALSE)
  }
```

I have named the sudoku puzzle 'puzzle', and call the function by the following:

```
sudoku_solve(puzzle)
```

Comment: So, what does your ‘puzzle’ argument look like?

Comment: it's a 9 by 9 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the following statement, you are not passing any value to the function and x does not have a default value either.

```
if(sudoku_solve()){ # are all i's valid?
    return(TRUE) # All i's valid
}
```

Hence, although the argument is initially passed, when the function is called again after the loop, it is called without an argument. So you pass to free_sq(x) inside sudoku_solve(), and it gives an error.

```
empty_sq <- free_squ(x)
```

Make sure you are passing a value to sudoku_solve or else set the default value for x wither in sudoku_solve or in the free_squ class/function.

Comment: Hello, yes I've tried that. When I define x prior to the the running of the function, or replace it with 'puzzle' it still says that it is not defined. Also when i use if(sudoku_solve(x){ it causes an infinite loop

Comment: 'Error: C stack usage  7970320 is too close to the limit' is the error I get when I pass if(sudoku_solve(x)

Comment: @James.H You got an answer to your question. You should cast an upvote. If you want further effort you should read [ask] and post a [MCVE].

Comment: @42 I tried his suggestions before even asking the question, so I didn't see that as answering my problem as it just leads to further issues.